# error django 1.7 setting auth user model

Tags: python, django, django-models

i want to make foreign key and use settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL but i am getting error like this:

```
    ERRORS:
kerajinan.Product.author: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
```

this is setting.py

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'kerajinan',
    'bootstrap3',
    'registration',
)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'kerajinan.UserProfile'
```

and this model.py:

```
    from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.db.models import ImageField
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin

class Product(models.Model):
    author          = models.ForeignKey('settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL')
    userprofile     = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title;
```

can you help solve this problem?

Comment: Show your auth model class

Answer (score 2):

You've used the literal string "settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL" in your ForeignKey. You should use the actual setting value.

```
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```